# how to pass jasper file path to subreport of subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using iReport tool in conjunction with JasperReports 1.3.4.

I have a master report, which contain two subreports. One of these subreports has an embedded subreport. All of the .jasper files reside in the same directory.

iReport generated the parameter called `SUBREPORT_DIR`. The subreportExpression expresses the subreport filename as `![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport.jasper"]`.

Everything works great when the report is generated from within iReport. But, I have a small Java web appplication that I am trying to use to generate reports. I pass a `"SUBREPORT_DIR"` parameter to `JasperFillManager.fillReport(String sourceFileName, Map parameters, JRBeanCollectionDatasource)`. This `SUBREPORT_DIR` is set to the directory in which the master report is located.

fillReport throws an exception:

```
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Could not load object from location :
    .sub-subreport.jasper.
```

It appears that the first subreport is trying to process its `subreport(embedded subreport)`, but the `SUBREPORT_DIR` is not being resolved, or used properly to generate the name of the sub-subreport.

Is there something I'm missing? How should this scenario be handled?

Comment: From the exception message it seems that you are using a "." as the SUBREPORT_DIR parameter. If so, try using "./" or just "."

Comment: where to put "./" ? i am confusing

Comment: Right now I suppose that you are using: 
parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", ".");
JasperFillManager.fillReport(String sourceFileName, Map parameters, JRBeanCollectionDatasource);

Try using:
parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "");

Comment: In java class Param, i am setting param like ..param.put("SUBREPORT_DIR",filepath) where filepath =request.getSession(true).getServletContext().getRealPath("/jsps/jrxmls/")  . as per your advice how can i change it to "".then it will pass null value right?

Comment: It will pass an empty String value. That will make the master reports look for their subreports in their current path. Also, are your .jasper files in the same folder of your .jrxml files?

Comment: @Gedim..see my edited part also..

Comment: yes all my .jrxm and .jasper files on same folder.

Comment: @Gedim.. after changing param to "./" it giving error like "JRException:Report Generation Exception: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Could not load object from location : ./Collateral_Subreport1.jasper" ... now it is not loading the first "subreport1" also

Comment: One easy solution would be to remove the ${SUBREPORT_DIR} parameter completely and use the ![CDATA["subreport.jasper"] expression for your subreports.

Comment: can you give me some sample code.. i am totally frustrated on this issue.

Comment: @Gedmin... atlast i fixed ..i directly fetch context root in jsp page  and pass to jasper through bean field...

Answer (score 5):

Click in `Subreport1`, go to the `properties tab -> Subreport properties -> Parameters`

You will pass your '**MasterReport**' `SUBREPORT_DIR` parameter as a parameter to '**Subreport1**'.
Create this entry:

Name: `SUBREPORT_DIR`
Expression: `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}`

Don't forget to recompile your reports and make sure to republish your web app in the application server.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and setting the SUBREPORT_DIR to the full package name containing my reports worked.

For example:

"com/mycomp/myapp/reports/"

Our set ups are similar in that you have all reports in the same directory.  The difference is I am running my app from the desktop (Java SE).  However, my reports were located in a jar file.  When I tried to set teh SUBREPORT_DIR to c:\path\to\app\myapp.jar!\com\mycomp\myapp\reports Jasper failed to locate the file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As [Marcio already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3925275/50776), your `SUBREPORT_DIR` parameter has to be passed from the calling report to the subreport.
Using relative path with `.`or `./` is not reliable, an absolute path is always to prefer.

So you have to write in your jrxml file:

```
<subreport isUsingCache="false">
    <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "mySubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

You have to pass the `subreportParameterExpression` with the `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}`, elswise it won't pass the parameters (only setting `<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR"/>` is not enough).

Answer (score 0):

just set `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}` as prompt and pass your value(the path to the directory may not be 
valid like `c:\something.jasper` instead of `c:\\something.jasper`)

Answer (score 0):

Put your compiled subReport under your java classpath, eg: Resources/subreport/test.jasper

refer to your subreport as "subreport/test.jasper" will work