# How include subreport in a parent directory into a report in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, report, subreport

How can I include a subreport (.jrxml) file which is located on the parent folder of a specified report in that report? Seems I can't use relative path for specifying subreport (It failed to compile when I want to use relative path like `../parent/subreport.jrxml`).

Comment: You can look at [how to pass jasper file path to subreport of subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702565/how-to-pass-jasper-file-path-to-subreport-of-subreport) question